# Create dropdown menu containing excel sheet's columns in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I want to create dropdown menu which will include columns: **avg_age_all**, **avg_age_men**, **avg_age_women** from Tables. So for example when I choose from menu **avg_age_men** only values from this column will be displayed on the map. Is it even possible? Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Create a parameter say `param1` with desired drop down values.

Secondly create a calculation field say `CF` with following calculation

```
CASE [PARAM1]
WHEN 'avg_age_all' THEN [avg_age_all]
WHEN 'avg_age_men' THEN [avg_age_men]
WHEN 'avg_age_women' THEN [avg_age_women]
END
```

Use this `CF` in the viz instead of your dimension, show param1 and you'll have a viz as desired.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. Got it with the help of https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/changing-views-using-parameters.htm